# Mount a NAS-Server on logon using Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking, cmd, nas

I have got 16 Laptops, 1 NAS-Server, and 3 Printers in an (isolated) Network

I want to run a Batch script (autostart.bat) when a user boots logs onto a Laptop which does the following:

- Run another Batch (autostart_server.bat) from the NAS which sets up the Printers on the
  Laptop. I put this in a seperate Batch file which is ran from the NAS
  because I dont want to run arround and change the local Batch on
  every of the 16 Laptops if, e.g. a new Printer is added to the
  Network.
- Adds a virtual Drive from the NAS where everyday-use files      are
  located

**Details about the NAS:**

- It requires a user Name and Password when you connect to it. there is
  no anonymous Login Feature or simmilar (At least I didnt find it (and
  I searched)).
- Every Employee has an Account on the NAS which name is containing the first letter of his forename, "_", and the surname e.g. j_doe for John Doe
  I figured it would be best to put the autostart_server.bat in a seperate virtual drive called 'Startup'

**The Problem**

I dont want to ask the User for his NAS credentials yet cause he might not need the files in this session

So I created a NAS Account with Name autostart_user and Password 123456 which I can use to log into the NAS to run the autostart_server.bat

Now I log into the NAS, run the autostart_server.bat, everything is fine for now.

But now I want to add the virtual drive with the files for everyday-use. when I mount it (using NET USE) it automatically adopts the autostart_user and its password. So now the User is logged into the NAS with the wrong Account

When the User now tries to access his files, he is getting promted to enter his credentials, because the autostart_user has no read/write rights on that virtual drive

Even if the User enters his credentials right, the NAS throws an error saying he doesnt have read rights

**Possible Solutions I thought of:**

I need to connect to the NAS, run autostart_server.bat and somehow disconnect again (NET USE A: /DELETE doesn't do the Job)

Next Thing is that I would like to add the virtual drive, without loggin in yet so the User gets prompted when he tries to Access the drive

**My Code so far:**

```
@echo off
TITLE Autostart Preload

SET NASIP=192.168.0.3

ping -n 1 %NASIP% | find "TTL=" >nul

if errorlevel 1 (
    echo NAS not available
    timeout /T 10
) else (
    NET USE A: /DELETE

    NET USE A: \\%NASIP%\userfiles "123456" /USER:startup_user /PERSISTENT:NO

    \\%NASIP%\Startup\autostart_server.bat

    echo Autostart executed

    pause
)
```

Comment: why do you assign a drive letter /`A:`) , if you don't use it (`\\%NASIP%\Startup\autostart_server.bat`?

Comment: Cause this Drive should later appear under 'Computer' (Win7) as a Networkdrive to the User

Comment: `I need to connect to the NAS, run autostart_server.bat and ... disconnect again`. Do you need to disconnect or keep the connection?

Comment: Well technically i dont need to disconnect but i need to logout with that autostart_user